# Nuget packages doubled

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I have a visual studio solution with several projects all specifing their own packages.config.

If I run "nuget restore blablabla.sln", I get e.g. grpc.core\1.11.0 in my packages folder.

If I let Visual Studio do this I will get grpc.core\1.11.0 **and** Grpc.Core.1.11.0 in my packages folder both with the same contents!?

Why is that?
BR,
Daniel

Comment: Your package reference has been declared as `<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Core" Version="1.11.0" />` ?

Comment: Nope. Visual Studio 2017 generated packages.config. PackageReferences are only on .NET Core projects if I remember correctly. Mine are all .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

> Nuget packages doubled

According to your description, you should have more than two package resources in your Visual Studio with same nuget package `grpc.core\Grpc.Core` (Ignore case). As we know, nuget is not case sensitive when searching and restoring packages. So:

1. Double check the packages **grpc.core\1.11.0** and **Grpc.Core.1.11.0** are the same except capitalization.
2. Clean up your `\packages` folder before restoring the nuget from
   Visual Studio.
3. If you confirm the above, please check if your package feed have the nuget package `grpc.core\1.11.0`. You can remove it, since it have the same contents as package `Grpc.Core.1.11.0` in the default package source `nuegt.org`.

Hope this helps.